# How to extarct the mask from a Dask masked array?

Tags: python, dask, masked-array

In [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/), there is a class called [`MaskedArray`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.array.ma.masked_array.html), corresponding to the NumPy class [with the same name](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray). The NumPy class has the methods `getdata` and `getmask`, which it seems like the Dask class is also supposed to have; however, I can only find a mention of `getmask` for the Dask class as red text at the `getdata` [documentation page](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.array.ma.getdata.html), and when I try to call it in my script, I get

```
AttributeError: module 'dask.array.ma' has no attribute 'getmask'
```

So, where is the `getmask` method for the Dask class? Do I need to obtain the mask in some other way? Or isn't it possible to extract a mask from a Dask masked array at all in the same way as it is possible for a NumPy masked array, and if so, why not? Do I have to convert the Dask masked array to a NumPy masked array before I can extract the mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the module method [`dask.array.ma.getmaskarray`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.array.ma.getmaskarray.html). Here's a simple example:

```py
In [2]: import dask.array.ma
   ...: import dask.array
   ...: import numpy as np

In [3]: arr = dask.array.from_array(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4), chunks=(2, 2))
   ...: mask = dask.array.from_array(np.random.random(size=(4, 4)) > 0.5, chunks=(2, 2))
   ...: masked = dask.array.ma.masked_array(arr, mask)

In [4]: masked
Out[4]: dask.array<masked_array, shape=(4, 4), dtype=int64, chunksize=(2, 2), chunktype=numpy.MaskedArray>

In [5]: da_mask = dask.array.ma.getmaskarray(masked)

In [6]: da_mask
Out[6]: dask.array<getmaskarray, shape=(4, 4), dtype=bool, chunksize=(2, 2), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>

In [7]: da_mask.compute()
Out[7]:
array([[False, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False]])
```

You can view the list of available module-level methods in the [Dask Masked Array API Documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/array-api.html#masked-arrays).